# Amazon MWS Unknown Marketplaces

Tags: amazon-mws

Based on Amazon MWS documentation, we have 11 marketplaces:
http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_Endpoints.html

But when I call Sellers API *ListMarketplaceParticipations*, I receive the response below. The first (sim1.stores.amazon.com) and last (siprod.stores.amazon.ca) ones are not in the documentation. Does anybody know about these two marketplaces?

```
<ListMarketplaces>
  <Marketplace>
    <MarketplaceId>A2ZV50J4W1RKNI</MarketplaceId>
    <DefaultCountryCode>US</DefaultCountryCode>
    <DomainName>sim1.stores.amazon.com</DomainName>
    <Name>Non-Amazon</Name>
    <DefaultCurrencyCode>USD</DefaultCurrencyCode>
    <DefaultLanguageCode>en_US</DefaultLanguageCode>
  </Marketplace>
  <Marketplace>
    <MarketplaceId>A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2</MarketplaceId>
    <DefaultCountryCode>CA</DefaultCountryCode>
    <DomainName>www.amazon.ca</DomainName>
    <Name>Amazon.ca</Name>
    <DefaultCurrencyCode>CAD</DefaultCurrencyCode>
    <DefaultLanguageCode>en_CA</DefaultLanguageCode>
  </Marketplace>
  <Marketplace>
    <MarketplaceId>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MarketplaceId>
    <DefaultCountryCode>US</DefaultCountryCode>
    <DomainName>www.amazon.com</DomainName>
    <Name>Amazon.com</Name>
    <DefaultCurrencyCode>USD</DefaultCurrencyCode>
    <DefaultLanguageCode>en_US</DefaultLanguageCode>
  </Marketplace>
  <Marketplace>
    <MarketplaceId>A1MQXOICRS2Z7M</MarketplaceId>
    <DefaultCountryCode>CA</DefaultCountryCode>
    <DomainName>siprod.stores.amazon.ca</DomainName>
    <Name>SI CA Prod Marketplace</Name>
    <DefaultCurrencyCode>CAD</DefaultCurrencyCode>
    <DefaultLanguageCode>en_CA</DefaultLanguageCode>
  </Marketplace>
</ListMarketplaces>
```

Comment: https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=333998

Comment: yeah I asked it there too. But the answer is not confirming the answer below. Thanks @Keyur

Answer (score 2):

I know from previous discussions that there used to be "sandbox" MWS accounts but that Amazon is now hesitant to give anybody access to those. I never had a sandbox account myself, so some of the following is just an informed guess:

```
ATVPDKIKX0DER  is Amazon.com, using USD and english (en_US)
A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2 is Amazon.ca, using CAD and english (en_CA)
```

This matches [the official documentation](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_Endpoints.html).

```
A2ZV50J4W1RKNI is called "Non-Amazon", using USD and english (en_US), might be the american sandbox
A1MQXOICRS2Z7M is called "SI CA Prod Marketplace", using CAD and english (en_CA), might be the canadian sandbox
```

If you don't have a "sandbox" account and accompanying documentation I would stay away from those marketplaces.

I tried replicating this by calling ListMarketplaceParticipations myself, but have not succeeded in getting anything but an error: *"We encountered an internal error. Please contact the MWS team if this problem persists."*

Edit: I don't think public documentation on those systems exist. Googling "A2ZV50J4W1RKNI" gives 4 results, one of which is on the [Amazon forums](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=323008&tstart=0) stating *Those Marketplaces id's might be used for internal purpose.* and *Sorry, Unfortunately we don't have many details about those unknown marketplace id's.* Googling "A1MQXOICRS2Z7M" only leads here.

Comment: Do you have any sorts of documentation that can confirm this? @Hazzit

Answer (score 2):

The SI CA Prod Marketplace is definitely NOT a sandbox marketplace, as our customers have valid sales in that marketplace. Based on the data, such as a SHOPIFY MerchantOrderId, an AmazonOrderId beginning with S01 and a FulfillmentChannel of Amazon, I would assume that this is a Canadian MCF marketplace, meaning fulfilled by Amazon, but sold off-Amazon. In the US, these just appear as a SalesChannel of Non-Amazon, but the SI marketplaces may have been created to differentiate the off-Amazon sales in different marketplaces from the US marketplace designator.